# Es recomendable usar dos constructores en Java?

Tags: java

hola amigos tengo una duda que para mi es algo que no entiendo, los constructores inicializan los objetos de una clase, pero cual es el proposito de la sobre carga de constructores, en general porque existe ese termino en java?, porque es posible crear varios constructores en java pero con diferentes parametros?, cual es su proposito general?

porque ejemplo con estos dos constructores :

```html
  public class HelloWorld{
  
  public HelloWorld(int edad){
    
  }
  public HelloWorld(int  numero){
    
  }
  }
```

Comment: Porque no siempre un objeto se crea de la misma manera supongamos que tiene una clase de tipo persona donde siempre va a pedir un nombre sexo y pero son en algunas ocaciones se podria especficar la edad ya que no se podria conocer por un determinado motivo y no es muy buena idea pasar informacion incorrecta asi que sea crea 2 constructores uno donde se piede la informacion + edad y otro solo la informacicon clasica(nombre y sexo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La sobrecarga se da cuando se quiere ejecutar el mismo método con diferentes parámetros. Por ejemplo:

```
public int sumar(int op1, int op2){
    return op1 + op2;
}

public int sumar(int op1, int op2, int op3){
    return op1 + op2 + op3;
}
```

Para el caso de los constructores es igual sirven para tener varias formas de crear un objeto, un ejemplo es la clase Random(que se usa para generar números aleatorios) que tiene dos constructores uno que no pide parámetros y otro que pide un numero entero que representa una semilla.

Comment: oh Muchas gracias @AlexanderCastroRomero

Comment: Yo tenia un profe que decía que es de novatos no sobrecargar al menos una vez el constructor, uno sin parámetros que es el por defecto y otro con parámetros. En ese ultimo caso un ejemplo seria un constructor que recibe una instancia de ese mismo tipo de clase. Y recuerden eso decía mi profesor, no yo. Pero si tiene sentido, ¿no?

Answer (score 1):

La sobrecarga te la posibilidad de hacer el mismo metodo con distintos parametros , en el caso de los constructores igual con este puedes hacer muchas cosas.
Un ejemplo practico seria tener un constructor que reciba un entero y tener otro que no reciba nada y cuando se invoque a este llame al otro con un entero , seria como tener un por defecto.

> public class Ejemplo{
>
> Ejemplo(int x){
>
> System.out.println("EL numero es "+x);
>
> }
>
> Ejemplo(){
>
> Ejemplo(2);
>
> }
>
> }

De esta forma puedes crear objetos con un numero por defecto con facilidad , es una de las muchas utilidades que tiene la sobrecarga